# Blender bge camera edge clipping aproach help

Tags: python, game-engine, camera

i have this thing on the bge: "see the image"
\n
while the camera moves, the origin of my objects(tiled ground) reachs the edge of the camera" so blender stops rendering it because gets offscreen.

im a python intermediate user, know the bge "well enough".

movin the object origin would solve it momentaneusly, but i'll also have to repositionate the mesh... entering on triky calculations for bunch of objects instances.
this is the question:
is there a way to tell blender to clip [Camera settings] a little offscreen horizontally ??

you know... to render these tiles on the edge of the screen??

tryed tweaking the camera settings but with no clue. 
multi resolution meshes but to increese the vertex count for an indeed  offscreen object seems stupid.
thinked on replace the meshes on smaller ones, s the same, just make gaps smaller but + calculation and trickering.

any idea will be apreciated...
thank you! have blend day ;)
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your question is very hard to read. Could you please consider reformatting/organizing the stuff so that it's easy for people to read it?

Comment: it seams tricky, i have some other ideas. with the viewport perhaps, or the render and texture module, bgl draw fill poligons, seem way to much... it has to be a simpler way.

Answer (score -2):

here are some ideas google doped ive found useful

https://blenderartists.org/t/update-object-origin/553245

https://github.com/UPBGE/blender/issues/211

the best way seems to be adding other camera.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HgXAv9csJu0&index=3&list=PLBF3FB2A571A6BB7C

dont know if i have to delete the questions...??? close thread..?? 
thanks for the help

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/64944)

Comment: well im still waiting for a better solution. if someone knows how to make blender to clipp little offset screen. ill apreciate it. 
Like still theres no better "solution" i will try replacing these meshes for specific models to tiles on the edges, ¿the right answer? i dont know theres probably tons o ways of do this, that's what i was asking. the best way to acheive the goal (render these tiles at the edge). i could'nt found any reference to this task else than the cause (the origin outside of the camera view)

Comment: It's better to mind the rules of the platform. That way people are not distracted from answering the question. Also reacting to the comments asking to form the question in an easier to understand manner might be a good idea if you wish to improve the chances of getting a good answer.